# Error in R pdfetch_boe from pdfetch package

Tags: r

```
require(pdfetch)

pdfetch_BOE("LPMVWYR", "2012-01-01")
```

generates result

Error in utils::download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = T) :
cannot open URL 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/iadb/fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&SeriesCodes=LPMVWYR&CSVF=TN&VPD=Y&UsingCodes=Y&Datefrom=01/Jan/2012&Dateto=22/Feb/2021'
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = T) :
cannot open URL 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/iadb/fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&SeriesCodes=LPMVWYR&CSVF=TN&VPD=Y&UsingCodes=Y&Datefrom=01/Jan/2012&Dateto=22/Feb/2021': HTTP status was '500 Internal Server Error'

The same happens if I try to run the same code here:
https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by itself. Looks like a glitch from Bank of England side